# How do I tackle revolting Christians (Christian revolutions)?

Tags: pc, shogun-2-total-war

Two of my provinces are constantly spawning Christian rebels, these provinces are on the edge of my territory, bordering on my enemies territory.

Are there any steps I can take to stop this?

Could there be a spy or Shinobi in these provinces causing trouble.

**UPDATE**

My territory now pushes far past it's previous boundaries but these two provinces are still spawning Christian rebels.

Comment: Man, without context, this question is hilarious.

Comment: @Liesmith yeah _Revolting Christians_ definitely has a certain ring to it alright...

Comment: "Revolting Christians" was the name of my Christian Punk band in college.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have mentioned in my question, but the original offending province was Bungo.

Bungo has a nanban port, which provides +3.5 to Christianity in that province and once Christianity reaches 100, it spreads to the surrounding provinces. So I need to destroy that port and build me a nice Buddhist temple!

Comment: Of course if you want to keep getting their guns you should instead send a monk built for inspiring towns and maybe a metsuke while topping off your suppression with a garrison

Comment: I think a maxed out monastery plus a good monk or two can counter the nanban port's influence, but that's a pretty hefty investment and one set of guns every four turns may not be worth it.

Comment: You will better build the temples anyway and put monks and other buddhist elements. Also,you can convert your clan to Christinaty,but this can cause buddhist revolts.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put many troops to defend the castle.Meanwhile,bring buddhist priests and build temples to try to convert he people to buddhism or increase repression.Also,check if the neighbors have a Nanban Quarter or a Christian Building that can convert nearby provinces.